# JPA unique constraint validation

Tags: java, jpa, hibernate-validator

How to validate Multiple column unique constraint in JPA entity. Is there any Hibernate validator for this purpose. I have added @UniqueConstraint annotation. But it is not doing any validation.And I also want to customize the error message.

Answer (score 7):

The `@UniqueConstraint` is not related to hibernate-validator. It cannot be handled by java-only validation, it needs a trip to the database.

It tells hibernate that the database has a unique constraint. If the database does not have a unique constraint, I think the insert should pass.

Comment: Then in which way I can validate that?

Comment: It depends on what you want to be the result of the validation. If it's an exception - you will get one when you do the insert. If you want some boolean - you will have to send a query to check if it exists in the DB. Do you have a unique constraint in the DB?

Comment: @cdb then make a query before inserting to check if it is allowed. Or catch the constraint violation exception.